# Windows 10 emulator not working in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, windows-phone-emulator

I have visual studio 2015  and windows 10 Home edition .
when I have run the project Emulator following error occur.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyper-V is not included in Windows 10 Home Edition. It is only available in the Pro or Enterprise Editions.