# installing windows app from vs2015

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2015, ibm-mobilefirst, windows-phone-8-emulator

Hello all my operating system is **windows 10 home edition**.I am developing
an **hybrid mobile app** using **ibm mobilefirst** for **windows phone8.**
When i open The developed .csproj file from mobilefirst in **visual studio 15  community edition** and preview it i get the following error **CANT START WINDOWS EMULATOR THE WINDOWS PHONE EMULATOR REQUIRES HYPER-V**. When i try to run on a device mode on visual studio i get the following error **your windows phone is developer locked** and i browse google to ms developer account signup it pops up with some price for developer account
when i directly paste apps and try to install in mobile it shows **cant install company app**. IS there anyway possible to test my app in windows mobile for free please help and thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried Googling for the Hyper-V error message? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: i have googled and found that home edition doesnt support hyper-V

Answer (score 1):

Hyper-V is not included in Windows 10 Home Edition. It is only available in the Pro or Enterprise Editions [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401527/windows-10-emulator-not-working-in-visual-studio-2015)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to install your application in emulator so you need to enable your Hyper-V from the BIOS or better you just install it on device as you said you have device problem of device locker just do one thing

1) search in all programs "PhoneReg.exe"
2)connect your device to the PC.
3)once device detected by "phoneReg" just click on button register
4)after this it will ask you for microsoft acount detail just fill userid password then your device will be unlocked for the devlopment and sideloading.

Hope dis will help you